# Observable.Generate Delays results

Tags: c#, system.reactive, scheduler, observable

The following code delays the results by 2 seconds. What I want is to return the results immediately but to launch a new observable every 2 seconds. What I am missing?

**OUTPUTS:**

```
**The current output is:**
05: 1. Run
07 Result: 1

07: 2. Run
09 Result: 2

09: 3. Run
11 Result: 3


**Desired output is:**
05: 1. Run
05 Result: 1

07: 2. Run
07 Result: 2

09: 3. Run
09 Result: 3
```

**CODE:**

```
    var sources = Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(i =>
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}. Run", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("ss"), i);

                                                    return Observable.Return(i, CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance);
                                                });

    Observable.Generate(sources.GetEnumerator(), e => e.MoveNext(), e => e, e => e.Current, e => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000), ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
              .Merge()
              .Timestamp()
              .Do(r =>
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("{0} Result: {1}{2}", r.Timestamp.ToString("ss"), r.Value, Environment.NewLine);
                  },
                  ex =>
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                  },
                  () =>
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Completed");
                  })
              .Subscribe();
```

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you are after here - I presume your comment to Paul's answer means you want variable data-driven intervals, but beyond that there's (to my trained Rx eye) a lot of "weird stuff" in your code. Perhaps it would be useful to explain in non-rx terms what you are trying to achieve. For example, it's not all clear why you are creating the `IEnumerable<IObservable>` for the `sources` as it looks like `IEnumerable<>` would do. It's also not clear if the `sources` is supposed to contain data indicating the desired intervals.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .SelectMany(_ => GenerateAnObservable())
    .Subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: I use generate for the variable period selector in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about replace your current `Observable.Generate` with this:

```
Observable
    .Generate(
        0,
        i => true,
        i => i + 1,
        i => i,
        i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i == 0 ? 0 : 2000),
        ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .Zip(sources, (g, s) => s)
```

I got this result:

```
41: 1. Run
41 Result: 1

43: 2. Run
43 Result: 2

45: 3. Run
45 Result: 3

47: 4. Run
47 Result: 4

49: 5. Run
49 Result: 5

51: 6. Run
51 Result: 6

53: 7. Run
53 Result: 7

55: 8. Run
55 Result: 8

Completed
```